# pygatt connects but unable to subscribe vs. bleak connects and able to subscribe: why isn't bleak replicable with pygatt?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to subscribe to single characteristic on a BLE device. Using `bleak` I am able to connect to the device and then write / subscribe to characteristics. With virtually identical code using `pygatt`, I can connect to the same device using my BLED112 dongle, but am not able to write/subscribe to that same characteristic.

`bleak` test program:

```
import sys
import os
import asyncio
import aioconsole


from bleak import BleakClient


ADDRESS = '28686572-5A71-435E-952A-6F4292F5B04A'
#ADDRESS = '00:55:DA:B7:98:9C'
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = '273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358'

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    ADDRESS = sys.argv[1]
    CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = sys.argv[2]


def notification_handler(sender, data):
    """Simple notification handler which prints the data received."""
    print("{0}: {1}".format(sender, data))


async def run(address):

    async with BleakClient(address) as client:

        await client.connect()
        print("Is connected")

        # start notifications on control characteristic
        await client.start_notify('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', notification_handler)
        # write to control handle, set preset to 21
        await client.write_gatt_char('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', bytearray([0x04, 0x70, 0x32, 0x31, 0x0a]), False)
        # write to control handle get device info
        await client.write_gatt_char('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', bytearray([0x03, 0x76, 0x31, 0x0a]), False)
        # write to control handle for resume
        await client.write_gatt_char('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', bytearray([0x02, 0x64, 0x0a]), False)
        # start notifications on TP9
        await client.start_notify('273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', notification_handler)
        # wait for input
        await aioconsole.ainput('Running: Press a key to quit')
        await client.stop_notify('273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ["PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG"] = str(1)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run(ADDRESS))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 bleaktest.py                                         
Is connected
13: bytearray(b'\x08{"rc":0}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
13: bytearray(b'\x10{"ap":"headset",\x00\x00\x00')
13: bytearray(b'\x13"sp":"Blackcomb_rev')
13: bytearray(b'\x03B",":"Blackcomb_rev')
13: bytearray(b'\x10"tp":"consumer",rev')
13: bytearray(b'\x0c"hw":"10.6",er",rev')
13: bytearray(b'\x07"bn":2,0.6",er",rev')
13: bytearray(b'\x0e"fw":"1.0.21",",rev')
13: bytearray(b'\r"bl":"1.0.0",,",rev')
13: bytearray(b'\x07"pv":1,.0.0",,",rev')
13: bytearray(b'\x07"rc":0}.0.0",,",rev')
Running: Press a key to quit
13: bytearray(b'\x08{"rc":0}0.0",,",rev')
31: bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x80\x08\x00z\xa8\xdfL@\x00\xa8!\xb6p\xa0\x00hA\x92')
31: bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x9d0\x00]q\x86\xb5\xb0\x00+\xaf\x96\xf3#\x1a\x00\t\x88')
31: bytearray(b'\x00\x02\x1bh\x04\x00\x06\x14\x18\t\xe8\x00\x05&\x13\xdc%\x00\x01\x97')
...
31: bytearray(b'\x00\x19_\xf1\x85\x9e\xc0\x00GP\xe9\xcb@\x00\t\x9c\xaf\x11\x15\xe4')
...
```

As you can see from the output, the writes are successful because of the response handles. And the subscriptions are clearly functional given the responses from both the control characteristic and the secondary characteristic.

`pygatt` test program:

```
import pygatt
import time
from binascii import hexlify

from pygatt.backends.backend import BLEAddressType



def handle_data(handle, data):
    """
    handle -- integer, characteristic read handle the data was received on
    raw_value -- bytearray, the data returned in the notification
    """

    print(hexlify(data))

#adapter = pygatt.GATTToolBackend('hci0') linux backend
adapter = pygatt.BGAPIBackend()

try:
    adapter.start()
    device = adapter.connect('00:55:DA:B7:98:9C', address_type = BLEAddressType.public)
    print("Is connected")
    # start notifications on control characteristic
    device.subscribe('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', callback = handle_data, wait_for_response = True)
    # write to control handle, set preset to 21
    device.char_write('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', bytearray([0x04, 0x70, 0x32, 0x31, 0x0a]), wait_for_response = True)
    # write to control handle get device info
    device.char_write('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', bytearray([0x03, 0x76, 0x31, 0x0a]), wait_for_response = True)
    # write to control handle for resume
    device.char_write('273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', bytearray([0x02, 0x64, 0x0a]), wait_for_response = True)
    time.sleep(5)
    # subscribe to eeg characteristic
    device.subscribe('273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358', callback = handle_data, indication = False, wait_for_response = True)
    time.sleep(5)
finally:
    print("Adapter stopped")
    adapter.stop()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 pygatttest.py
Is connected
Adapter stopped
```

The `pygatt` program is able to connect to the device (I can see the indicator light change states from flashing to solid), but subscription fails. I don't know if `char_write` is working because I don't receive a return notification. Am in the process of trying the `logging` module to figure out more per the comments below.

Updated output with `logging` enabled:

```
$ python3 pygatttest.py    
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Initialized new BGAPI backend
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Auto-detecting serial port for BLED112
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Found 4 serial USB devices
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port - n/a
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.usbmodem11 - Low Energy Dongle - CDC data
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:USB device: Low Energy Dongle - CDC data VID=0x2458 PID=0x0001 on /dev/cu.usbmodem11
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found BLED112 on serial port /dev/cu.usbmodem11
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Resetting and reconnecting to device for a clean environment
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Opening connection to serial port (attempt 1)
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Auto-detecting serial port for BLED112
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Found 4 serial USB devices
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port - n/a
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.usbmodem11 - Low Energy Dongle - CDC data
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:USB device: Low Energy Dongle - CDC data VID=0x2458 PID=0x0001 on /dev/cu.usbmodem11
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found BLED112 on serial port /dev/cu.usbmodem11
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Opening connection to serial port (attempt 1)
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Auto-detecting serial port for BLED112
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Found 3 serial USB devices
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port - n/a
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Failed to open serial port
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../pygatt/backends/bgapi/bgapi.py", line 171, in _open_serial_port
    serial_port = self._serial_port or self._detect_device_port()
  File ".../pygatt/backends/bgapi/bgapi.py", line 147, in _detect_device_port
    raise BGAPIError("Unable to auto-detect BLED112 serial port")
pygatt.backends.bgapi.exceptions.BGAPIError: Unable to auto-detect BLED112 serial port
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Opening connection to serial port (attempt 2)
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Auto-detecting serial port for BLED112
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Found 3 serial USB devices
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port - n/a
...
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Failed to open serial port
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../pygatt/backends/bgapi/bgapi.py", line 171, in _open_serial_port
    serial_port = self._serial_port or self._detect_device_port()
  File ".../pygatt/backends/bgapi/bgapi.py", line 147, in _detect_device_port
    raise BGAPIError("Unable to auto-detect BLED112 serial port")
pygatt.backends.bgapi.exceptions.BGAPIError: Unable to auto-detect BLED112 serial port
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Opening connection to serial port (attempt 3)
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Auto-detecting serial port for BLED112
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Found 4 serial USB devices
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port - n/a
...
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:Checking serial USB device: /dev/cu.usbmodem11 - Low Energy Dongle - CDC data
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.util:USB device: Low Energy Dongle - CDC data VID=0x2458 PID=0x0001 on /dev/cu.usbmodem11
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found BLED112 on serial port /dev/cu.usbmodem11
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Running receiver
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Disabling advertising
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.gap_set_mode: 58>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.gap_set_mode packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.sm_set_bondable_mode: 51>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.sm_set_bondable_mode packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Stopping any outstanding GAP procedure
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.gap_end_procedure: 61>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.gap_end_procedure packet: Device in wrong state
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Connecting to device at address 00:55:DA:B7:98:9C (timeout 5s)
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.sm_set_bondable_mode: 51>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.sm_set_bondable_mode packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.gap_connect_direct: 60>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.gap_connect_direct packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<EventPacketType.connection_status: 11>] within 5.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.connection_status packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Connection status: handle=0x0, flags=5, address=0xb'9c98b7da5500', connection interval=75.000000ms, timeout=1000, latency=0 intervals, bonding=0xff
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Connected to 00:55:DA:B7:98:9C
Is connected
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Looking up handle for characteristic 273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Fetching characteristics for connection 0
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.attclient_find_information: 41>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.attclient_find_information packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed: 17>] within 30.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found approved characteristic 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found approved characteristic 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found approved characteristic 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found approved characteristic 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0008-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0009-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e000a-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e000b-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0002-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0004-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0005-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0006-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0007-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e000c-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
cDEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e000d-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e000e-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e000f-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0010-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Found custom characteristic 273e0011-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_find_information_found packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x3
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x4
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x7
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x9
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0xb
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0xe
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0xf
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0008-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x11
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x12
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0009-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x14
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x15
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e000a-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x17
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x18
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e000b-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x1a
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x1b
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0002-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x1d
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x1e
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x20
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x21
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0004-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x23
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x24
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0005-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x26
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x27
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0006-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x29
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x2a
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0007-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x2c
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x2d
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e000c-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x2f
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x30
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e000d-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x32
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x33
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e000e-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x35
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x36
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e000f-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x38
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x39
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0010-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x3b
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x3c
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic 0x273e0011-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 is handle 0x3e
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Characteristic descriptor 0x00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is handle 0x3f
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Found <Characteristic uuid=273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 handle=14>
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write: 43>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed: 17>] within 30.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed packet: Success
INFO:pygatt.device:Subscribed to uuid=273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Looking up handle for characteristic 273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Found <Characteristic uuid=273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 handle=14>
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write: 43>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed: 17>] within 30.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed packet: Write not permitted
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Looking up handle for characteristic 273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Found <Characteristic uuid=273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 handle=14>
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write: 43>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed: 17>] within 30.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed packet: Write not permitted
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Looking up handle for characteristic 273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Found <Characteristic uuid=273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 handle=14>
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write: 43>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed: 17>] within 30.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed packet: Write not permitted
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Looking up handle for characteristic 273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358
DEBUG:pygatt.device:Found <Characteristic uuid=273e0003-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358 handle=32>
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write: 43>] within 1.000000s
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a EventPacketType.connection_disconnected packet: Success
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Received a ResponsePacketType.attclient_attribute_write packet: Not connected
DEBUG:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Expecting a response of one of [<EventPacketType.attclient_procedure_completed: 17>] within 30.000000s
Adapter stopped
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Stopping
INFO:pygatt.backends.bgapi.bgapi:Stopping receiver
```

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting this information correctly, but it seems as if the subscription is working and that I'm receiving information but the callback is not being fired?

I tried the solution here: [pygatt: Unable to execute device.subscribe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888220/pygatt-unable-to-execute-device-subscribe) by adding the `time.sleep()` lines to my code, but the output did not change.

How can I translate my `bleak` program to `pygatt` and subscribe successfully using `pygatt`?

Comment: I have no way of knowing -> This statement is wrong, you can read data without subscribing as well. When I check the [source code](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt/blob/master/pygatt/device.py) I see that if you subscribe you are notified `log.info("Subscribed to uuid=%s", uuid)` but I can't see any error handling. Please add the output of `sudo btmon` so we can debug further.

Comment: In the bleak code you have `response=False` while in the pygattlib you `wait_for_response=True`. Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: @Mr.Panda thanks for the advice on logging, but I'm running this on Mac OSX, so no `btmon` command available. @ukBaz, yes tried both with `response = True` and `response = False` in `bleak`. Both work. Neither work for `pygatt.` If it's truly an OS issue, I'm not sure why I would be able to connect but not subscribe.

Comment: Looking at the [notification example](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt#notifications-example) for pygatt it has the `time.sleep()` statement in a `while True:` loop to stop the thread exiting. It has some comments in the example explaining in more detail why this is necessary. Your code doesn't have this while loop so I'm assuming that is the issue as you code exits before it gets any notifications.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the log, logs help a lot. Now I see that you can get the notification descriptors (`0x2902` ones), and subscribe `Subscribed to uuid=273e0001-4c4d-454d-96be-f03bac821358`.  However you get `Write is not permitted.` Write permission is determined by the peripheral (server) not by the central (client). But you said exact the same setup worked with `Bleak` which is confusing. Check if your BLE device allows writing. `Read` and `Write` are separate permissions.

Comment: @ukBaz With the `while` loop in place, it just hangs in the loop and never quits nor receives information. Output is simply `Is connected` and then nothing else. @Mr. Panda: yes, same exact setup worked with `Bleak`. When you say "check if your BLE device allows writing." Are you referring to the USB dongle on my mac being able to write to the connected peripheral? If so, any recommendations on how to check? If you're referring to the connected peripheral, I would imagine that if the `bleak` code is working, then the periph is indeed allowing writing because I'm getting the desired responses?